# How to place the Y-axis label vertically center align in apexcharts?

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I want to place Y-axis label vertically center in my ReactJS requirement, so I tried with `align: 'center'` and also with `verticalAlignment: 'center'` under y-axis label but I am unable to get the expected output.
Is there any other way to achieve this requirement?

Comment: I have the same requirement, does anyone has a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I found to do that is to get the max value in your series

```
series: [{
  data: [0, 24, 10,30]
}],
```

And set it yaxis the min and the max to be that max value. In that example 30

```
yaxis: {
  min: -30,
  max: 30,
},
```

This will make the 0 of the yaxis centered